# Netbeans Run Params with multiple parameters from commandline

Tags: java, netbeans, command-line, build.gradle, netbeans-platform

I have been using:
 `-Dnetbeans.run.params=-J-Xdebug...`

Recently i needed to add some plugin and it works as:
 `-Dnetbeans.run.params=-J-agentpath:...`

But the problem is when i use both in cmd they do not work.

I tried:
 `-Dnetbeans.run.params=-J-agentpath:..., -J-Xdebug...`

And there is not an error. It just do not work. Is there any solution to use multiple parameters to pass netbeans run params ? For clarification i use gradle to pass run command to commandline.

Comment: I would try to remove the comma between the parameters, wrap the whole `-Dnebeans.run.params=-J... -J...` with double quotes `"-Dnebeans.run.params=-J... -J..."`.

Comment: @SubOptimal This works perfectly. Thanks for your answer!